# Airflow CLI command does not find the SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN variable in Docker

Tags: docker, sqlalchemy, command-line-interface, airflow

I am new to running airflow in docker. To run a airflow cli command, it used to be simply possible to run `airflow trigger_dag etc`. However, that clearly doesn't work anymore right away.

I found out I can get 'in' the container by `docker exec -ti <container_name> bash`. However, if I then try to run an airflow cli command, I get the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 16, in <module>
        from airflow import configuration
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
        from airflow import settings
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 150, in <module>
        configure_orm()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 136, in configure_orm
        engine = create_engine(SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN, **engine_args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 424, in create_engine
        return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 50, in create
        u = url.make_url(name_or_url)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 211, in make_url
        return _parse_rfc1738_args(name_or_url)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 270, in _parse_rfc1738_args
        "Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string '%s'" % name)
    sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string ''
```

It looks like it doesn't take the SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN. However, if I run `printenv` it does show up.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue. My setup is Docker using Ubuntu 16.04. I used Python3.

When i print ENV, i realized AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN was set to blank. Once i fixed that the issue was resolved.

You said SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN, Environment variable should be referred to as **AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN**

Make sure it is setup correctly. The order of precedence in airflow is a) Environment variables 2) Configuration in airflow.cfg file [link](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/set-config.html)

Comment: Thanks for adding your experience in a concise way Krishna, welcome to SO!